# How to split id into multiple values in a new column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am having multiple Id's in my table i have to append value such 00,01,02...99

```
id                   newid
1768053             176805300
1768053             176805301
1768053             176805302
1768053             176805303
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
1768053             176805399
```

I am new to python please help me

Comment: Hi Priya, please show us what you have tried up to this point. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do i am very new to python @d_kennetz

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the DF using `apply`, transform **id** and **index** to strings and sum then using `rjust` to guarantee two decimal places when the index is less than 10.

```
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True) #ensure that the index is incremental
df['newid'] = df.apply(lambda x:  str(x.id) + str(x.name).rjust(2, '0'), axis = 1)

output:
    id      newid
0   1768053 176805300
1   1768053 176805301
2   1768053 176805302
3   1768053 176805303
```

Comment: getting this error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index'

Comment: can you show me what is the output for the command `type(yourDataName)` ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are new in Python, I suggest you to try this:

```py
import numpy as np

id = ['1768053']*11+['1768054']*12
newId = []

values, counts = np.unique(id, return_counts=True)

for i in range (len(values)) : 
    for y in range (counts[i]):
        if y<10 :
            newId.append(values[i]+str(0)+str(y))
        else:
            newId.append(values[i]+str(y))
```

```
In [1] : newId
Out [1] : 

['176805300',
 '176805301',
 '176805302',
 '176805303',
 '176805304',
 '176805305',
 '176805306',
 '176805307',
 '176805308',
 '176805309',
 '176805310',
 '176805400',
 '176805401',
 '176805402',
 '176805403',
 '176805404',
 '176805405',
 '176805406',
 '176805407',
 '176805408',
 '176805409',
 '176805410',
 '176805411']
```

Comment: i don't have single id '1768053'. I have id's 1768053,1768054,1768055.... like this so i want new 100 ids against single id

Comment: Although OP has provided a lack of information, the `pandas` tag is a potential indication that the data structure they're working with is a dataframe and not a list as you have demonstrated

Comment: I think maybe it's hard to stard Python with `Pandas`

Comment: @Priya I readapte my answer. You need to install numpy package on using `pip install numpy` in your __terminale__

Comment: instead of giving each id values can we take a column name ? @ Demont Zhang

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm using a python list there is no column name. Do you use pandas package ?

Comment: yes i am using pandas package i am having csv file using that i want to add a newid column

Comment: You can replace `ìd` by your column name but @Terry's solution is better

Answer (score 0):

I created the test DataFrame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['1768053', '1768053', '1768053', '1768054', '1768054',
           '1768054', '1768054', '1768055', '1768055'],
    'xx': list('ABCDEFGHI')})
```

(`xx` column represents "other" columns in your DataFrame).

Then we have to define a function to be applied soon:

```
def fn(src):
    ind = range(src.shape[0])
    return pd.Series([ f'{x}{n:02}' for x, n in
        zip(src.id, ind) ], index=src.index )
```

And to create the new column, apply the above function to each group
of equal *id*s:

```
df['newid'] = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)\
    .apply(fn).droplevel(0)
```